# Is there a way to define response models based on a schema in FastAPI websockets?

Tags: python, websocket, sqlalchemy, fastapi, jsonschema

## Question

Assume you have the following pydantic schema

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
```

and a fastapi server running websockets

```
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
        self.active_connections: list[WebSocket] = []
        self.db = db

    async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.accept()
        self.active_connections.append(websocket)

    def disconnect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        self.active_connections.remove(websocket)
    
    async def handler(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        data = await self.receive_json()
        json = self.get_items()
        # should send a list of items 
        await websocket.send_json(dict(json))

    def get_items(self) -> List[Item]:
        # apply the schema to the queried items then return
        return self.query(Item).all()
```

the following is the websocket endpoint

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def ws_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, manager: ConnectionManager = Depends()):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    try:
        while True:
            await manager.handle(websocket)
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
```

Is there a way to define response models for `ConnectionManager` methods such as `get_items` so that it returns json data with out manually going through the pain of converting the query results every time I need to returned data from the database

currently the shortest and closest way to response models that I found was list comprehension

```
return [dict(SingleBeacon(**vars(b))) for b in self.db.query(Beacon).all()]
```

but that isn't scalable and honestly isn't pleasant to look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decorators can help with code duplication but still no what I am looking for

```
def apply_schema(schema: Type[BaseModel]):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return [dict(schema(**vars(b))) for b in func(*args, **kwargs)]
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

you just pass the schema class and it formats the json output

```
@apply_schema(ItemSchema)
def get_items(self):
    return self.db.query(Item).all()
```